# handle checkbox with useFormik

Tags: reactjs, formik

How can I use `useFormik` hook with ` ?

I tried this but not working

```js
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      healthBackground: [],
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => alert(JSON.stringify(values)),
 });
 
 
 return (
 <formik>
 <input type="checkbox" {...formik.getFieldProps("healthBackground")} value="test1" />
 <input type="checkbox" {...formik.getFieldProps("healthBackground")} value="test2" />
 </formik>
 )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-benji-dfzph?file=/index.js) maybe you should change your code to something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-benji-dfzph?file=/index.js)

Comment: Your documentation link is leading to sandbox

Comment: wonderful!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!